# How to get Total Children in a Parent Serializer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I want to display the total number of Workers associated with a Ticket Counter in a parent (Ticket counter) serializer.

Below are the two Serializers:

```
class TicketCounterSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
 workers = WorkerToCounterSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)    
 class Meta:
     model = TicketCounter
     fields = (
               'ticket_counter_name',
               'ticket_counter_description',
               'ticket_counter_address',
               'workers',
               )


class WorkerToCounterSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
 class Meta:
     model = WorkerToTicketCounter
     fields = (
         'user',
         'ticket_counter',
         'worker',
     )
```

MODELS:

```
class TicketCounter(models.Model):
   user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   ticket_counter_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="")
   ticket_counter_description = models.CharField(max_length=1500, default="")
   ticket_counter_address = models.CharField(max_length=1500, default="")


class WorkerToTicketCounter(models.Model):
   user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   ticket_counter = models.ForeignKey(TicketCounter,related_name="workers")
   worker = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name='worker_for_ticket_counter')
```

Here is how I am getting result:

```
{
        "ticket_counter_name": "First",
        "ticket_counter_description": "firsty",
        "ticket_counter_address": "222fdssssss",
        "workers": [
            {
                "user": 1,
                "ticket_counter": 3,
                "worker": 4,

            },
            {
                "user": 1,
                "ticket_counter": 3,
                "worker": 5,

            },

        ]
 }
```

Here is how I want

```
{
        "ticket_counter_name": "First",
        "ticket_counter_description": "firsty",
        "ticket_counter_address": "222fdssssss",
        "workers": 2 # just the total count
 }
```

How to just display the total count?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with an *annotation*, and serialize it as an `IntegerField`, like:

```
class TicketCounterSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    num_workers = serializers.IntegerField()
    class Meta:
        model = TicketCounter
        fields = (
            'ticket_counter_name',
            'ticket_counter_description',
            'ticket_counter_address',
            'num_workers',
         )
```

In the `ViewSet`, we can then specify:

```
from django.db.models import Count

class TicketCounterViewSet(viewsets.ListApiView):
    queryset = TicketCounter.objects.annotate(num_workers=Count('workers'))
    serializer_class = TicketCounterSerializer
```

We thus annotate every `TicketCounter` object with an attribute `num_workers` that contains the number of *related* `WorkerToTicketCounter` object.

Personally however I think the modeling has some weird names: the `TicketCounter` does not really look like a counter. Although I do not know the full scope of your application, I think models named `Ticket`, and `Worker` make perhaps more sense.

Comment: I am not using ModelViewSet.  I am just using `ListApiView`

Comment: @Naroju: both have approximately the same interface, so replace `ModelViewSet` with `ListApiView` :)

Comment: May I know what is "workers" in Count ? Is it the related_name ? And Count is unresolved. Do we need to import `Count` ?

Comment: @Naroju: it is the related name, and the import statement is at the top of the code fragment.

Comment: will you please look at this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52149763/django-nested-serializers-for-not-direct-related-names